# Basic manual image slideshow JavaScript code is making all images invisible and throwing error

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, web-maker

I am trying to implement a simple image slider by drawing on info from several sources. The CSS and HTML seem to be set up fine but when I add in the JavaScript logic all images disappear. The console shows an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" which would suggest that the array of elements containing the images is empty. I console log this array in a line before the one throwing the error and get three images as expected.

Also, I am using Web Maker so using "onclick" is not an option. Any suggestions? I know this is basic stuff but I'm just not seeing the issue. (code below)

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myslider">
      <img class="slide" src="http://chromethemer.com/wallpapers/chromebook-wallpapers/download/work-space-3840x2160.jpg">
      <img class="slide" src="http://lindstrominsuranceagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/business.jpeg">
      <img class="slide" src="http://www.nomisconnections.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image-1377543510.jpg">
      <button id="left-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
      <button id="right-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
#myslider {
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  width: 700px;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
/*   opacity: 0; */
  transition: 1s;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("left-button").addEventListener("click", plusDivs(-1));
document.getElementById("right-button").addEventListener("click", plusDivs(1));

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  console.log("inside of plusDiv(n)");
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  console.log(x);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex=1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inserted your callback functions in the `addEventListener` methods in an invalid way. If you want to pass parameters in the function you should invoke the function inside an anonymous function.

You can:

***Insert the function-object if you do not need to use function parameters.***

```
function someFunction(){
   ...
}
elem.addEventListener('click', someFunction);
```

***Insert an anonymous function***

```
elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
   ...
});
```

***Insert a function with a parameter in an anonymous function***

```
function someFunction(parameter){
   ...
}
elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
   someFunction(parameter);
});
```

I recommend read up in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

PS: You really do NOT want to call your variables `x`, `n` and `i`. Use something more descriptive.

**Your code with updated `addEventListener` methods**

```js
document.getElementById("left-button").addEventListener("click", () => {plusDivs(-1)});
document.getElementById("right-button").addEventListener("click", () => {plusDivs(1)});

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex=1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#myslider {
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  width: 700px;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
/*   opacity: 0; */
  transition: 1s;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myslider">
  <img class="slide" src="http://chromethemer.com/wallpapers/chromebook-wallpapers/download/work-space-3840x2160.jpg">
  <img class="slide" src="http://lindstrominsuranceagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/business.jpeg">
  <img class="slide" src="http://www.nomisconnections.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image-1377543510.jpg">
  <button id="left-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
  <button id="right-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
</div>
```